# How to properly handle NSTimer calls?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nstimer

I am running into a situation where I'm not able to properly handle `NSTimer`.

In my app, I've an option of user chats (I'm not using XMPP because of a low budget project, but the chat is working through API calls ONLY). I've scheduled a timer at a time interval of 15 seconds. If any new chats available I'll get it and will update chat view.

Here's the working scenario:

1. As this is a `UITabbar` based app, a user will come to "Chat" tab.
2. A User will have a list of persons with whom he can chat.
3. A User will select any of a user – will push to Chat Screen.
4. Where all locally saved chats will be visible and an API call will be made for new chats, on success (or error) of API call, a timer will be scheduled to sync chats at a time interval of 15 seconds.
5. If a user goes back (pops), in `viewDidDisappear:` method, I'm invalidating the (running) timer.

In my Unit testing, if I'll continuously push & pop to/from Chat screen, there'll be multiple instances of that timer will get scheduled. I suspect, this is WRONG.

I'm not sure what I'm doing is correct or not though I need your help to understand the right and the correct way to get my functionality done. I guess here there's no need of the code for above explanation.

Comment: Why use a timer at all?  Seems very clunky.

Comment: If you wan to use timers you need to save then, so you can destroy when the user leaves the view.

Comment: You could also take a look at [this](https://github.com/search?l=Objective-C&q=parse+chat&ref=searchresults&type=Repositories).

Comment: Why don't you use push notification for it. I have implemented the same concept of chat using API. While receiving a push notification regarding a message, I am updating my chat view. Its already working very nicely.

Comment: @rob180, thank for the link, however, that's something that I don't need actually. I have already implemented working chat, if in case, I'll stop scheduling a timer to fetch new messages for a particular chat then, chat is working fine. But in my question, I'm only having an issue with timer handling for a particular case.

Comment: @Droppy, alright, any other good solution for this simple function implementation.

Comment: @hagile Use a mechanism that notifies you when data is available to read/write on the sockets.

Comment: @Droppy, For that at least, I should have a timer to fetch new chats from the server. I don't have any automatically fetching system :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First of all, why are you not exploring option of push notification? Polling server every 15 second is a bad design :-(.**

Second, when it comes to `NSTimer` it is important to start and stop them from the same thread. I would advise you encapsulate your timer start/stop code in below block always ensuring you deal on main thread with your timer.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I appreciate your advice, one question to clear with you, my app is not fully chat based app, this is a very basic (only 1-1 and text) functionality. You're right that polling server at every 15 seconds is not good. I'll surely add timer into dispatch queues for better performance, but still the approach is bad, is there any other way to accomplish this thing?

Comment: 1 sec, you suggested push notification, how exactly? Can you provide some hints?

Comment: Yes, as I said - explore Apple Push Notifications. Its clean, fast and saves network calls. With push notifications you can send minimum data to notify your app that there is something available then once your app gets notified by APNS, make a server call and update your chat view.

Comment: Oh yes, that would work, but for a reason, we don't have APNS integrated, we'll but not today&tomorrow. However, this is something that I would keep in mind for future implementation.

Comment: 1 last question regarding this only, as you suggested for APNS, what if I'll get 10 push within 20 seconds, I may already make call to fetch new chats, how do I handle that case?

Comment: Yeah - please investigate. APNS integration pretty simple and straight forward and makes perfect sense for your application. All the best :)!

Comment: When to send push notification is upto your server side implementation. I would want my server team to write an algorithm that sends out push notification judiciously and not bombard it for every chat every second. This is not a big deal - talk to your server team :)!

Comment: Yes, I suspect for that behaviour, eventually this would take extra cents. I think, for now, I would keep running my timer, however, thanks for your efforts in providing an answer. I'm going to accept your answer soon. Thanks again :)

Answer (score 0):

This is the way o usually work with `NSTimer`. Hope it helps.

```
@implementation MainViewController{
    NSTimer *myTimer

}

- (void)startTimer{
    //Prevents multiple timers at the same time.
    [myTimer invalidate];
    myTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:5.0f target:self selector:@selector(update) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}

- (void)update
{
    //Stops the timer if the view in not on the screen
    if (!(self.isViewLoaded && self.view.window)) {
        [myTimer invalidate];
    }
}

@end
```

Comment: But to fetch newly chats is the core functionality of the app and by applying your code it'll stop fetching new chats (as we're invalidating timer). So this would not help.

Comment: So you want something that is running all the time? Even if the app is not on that view?

Comment: Yes, that's what I've already implemented, but the problem comes when I constantly push/pop from the view controller where the timer is setting up.

Comment: If you want the timer to be always running. Create it on The `AppDelegate.h` and use notifications system to inform you view that new data was retrieved from the server.

Comment: Thanks for the tip :)